# "Lately I meet" vs. "lately I have been meeting"

Tags: present-simple, present-perfect-progressive

Is there any difference in meaning between *lately I meet* and *lately I have been meeting*? I would've thought that *lately* is used with the Present Perfect Continuous, but in the 23rd episode of the 8th season of *Friends*, Phoebe used it with the Present Simple. Here is the context:

> Phoebe: Ooh, this is it! (Looks in the window.) Oh, that’s him! That’s
> him!
>
> Joey: Great! Go get him.
>
> Phoebe: Wait a second, or maybe you can go in first.
>
> Joey: (looks in the window) He’s not really my type.
>
> Phoebe: No not you, Dr. Drake Remoray. You can ask him questions and
> see what’s he like. People tell doctors everything.
>
> Joey: But you said he was this great guy!
>
> Phoebe: But **lately** all the guys **I meet** seem really nice at first, then
> they turn out to be the biggest jerks.

Would the meaning change somehow if she would say *lately all the guys I have been meeting...* or *lately all the guys I am meeting...*?

Comment: The original is fine. It would be equally idiomatic for Phoebe to say *lately all the guys I **have been meeting** [turn out to be jerks]*, but I have to say that although it's "valid", your *all the guys I **am meeting*** smacks of "Indian English" to me.

Comment: Phoebe meets guys as part of her way of life (like she eats dinner, or watches movies). The word ***lately*** divides those guys into two "classes"; 1: *those she met quite a long time ago*, and 2: ***all the rest*** - including anyone she's meeting now, or will meet in the foreseeable future, as well as those she met ***recently / lately***. If it was important to clarify whether that second category included present and/or future meetings, you'd need to use a lot more words to make that distinction - it wouldn't just turn on the choice between ***meet / am meeting / have been meeting***.

Comment: Thank you for clearifying that! Let me get this right. So what you are saying is that "lately I meet", "lately I am meeting" and "lately I have been meeting" mean the same, right?

Comment: *In your exact context*, yes - they mean the same. But that doesn't necessarily mean they're "equivalent", since as pointed out above, the continuous present has noticeable (to me, at least) connotations with IE (or other "non-native Anglophone").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the example and your suggested alternative refer to an observed trend (nice at first, then turn out to be jerks) in a set of people (some guys). The change in tense affects the scope of the guys.

"**all the guys I have been meeting...**" would refer to a limited number of guys that you have repeatedly met.

"**all the guys I meet...**" suggests that you have been meeting guys and continue to meet new ones. In your example, this suggests that the trend observed so far may also continue to be true.

Comment: Thank you for the helful answer! Could you please tell me how "lately I meet" and "lately I am meeting are different?

Comment: In practice there isn't really any difference. The fine nuance of difference set out above effectively answers the question *If there **were** a difference, what would it be?* Except there isn't.

Comment: @Astralbee "all the guys I have been meeting..." would refer to a limited number of guys that you have repeatedly met. Couldn't it just mean she has been meeting various guys for a while, not necessarily repeatedly.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Do you agree with Astralbee that "all the guys I have been meeting" means she has met these guys repeatedly?

Comment: No, but it's unlikely I would *actually* "disagree" with Astralbee, so my guess is you've misunderstood exactly what was meant. The distinction made between Present Perfect and Simple Present in the above answer is *extremely* fine (it probably wouldn't occur to many native speakers to think of that distinction independently, but I'm guessing *most* would probably agree if it was *suggested* to them). What's going on  there is just that the Perfect form draws attention to "relevance to time of utterance", so the scope is more restricted to ***recent past*** (implying less time to meet guys).

Comment: ...in which context, if there's less time to meet them, there *will* be "less guys". But to conclude from this that using the Perfect there somehow "means" seeing the same limited number of guys repeatedly is probably a stretch too far. Anyway, it would be nothing to do with the "meaning" of the Perfect form itself - just a possible reason why the speaker *might* want to use a verb form that *inherently* focuses more on the recent past, where the Simple Present might be taken to imply ***always, all my life, with all the guys I've ever met***.

Comment: @fumblefingers fewer guys.

Comment: haha, that's why I'm unlikely to actually "disagree" with you! As you might already know, I don't care a jot about that "rule" (or indeed many others) - but I don't have to pass exams marked by test-setters who *do* care about it!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Could "meeting a limited number of guys repeatedly" mean meeting a limited number of various guys at different ocassions, not meeting the same guys repeatedly? It is the word "repeatedly" in Astralbee's answer that is confusing me.

Comment: Using #1 Present Perfect Continuous *(all the guys I **have been meeting**)* focuses more on those she's met ***lately***, whereas #2 Simple Present *(**meet**)* in such contexts tends to rope in every guy she ***ever*** met or ***will*** meet. Inevitably that implies ***fewer*** guys in case #1 because it covers a more restricted timeframe. *Maybe* the actual "number of guys" is even further reduced because she sees each of them more often / repeatedly, I don't know. Frankly, I think you're trying to wring more "precision" out of the words that is justified.

Comment: It's quite reasonable to contrast #1 *all the guys I **have been meeting*** with #3 *all the guys I **have met*** and say that *on average*, #1 more strongly implies meeting each individual guy ***more often*** than #3. But this is only an implication anyway, and not really something worth "learning" if it doesn't immediately strike you as something that makes sense (and therefore doesn't really need to be remembered / learned).

Comment: Generally speaking, it would make *no difference at all* which verb form Phoebe in OP's context used for *all the guys I **meet / have been meeting / have met** lately*. Your problem seems to be that you think English is far more "precise" than it actuially is. There's next to nothing to learn here apart from some very basic points. Present Perfect implies greater relevance to "time of utterance" than Simple Past, and the Continuous participle calls attention to something being a *process* rather than a completed act. That's probably all the average native speaker knows or cares about.

Comment: @ FumbleFingers So "all the guys I have been meeting lately" doesn't necessarily mean I've been meeting each of these guys repeatedly. That is what I'd like to know.